# Input value not updated on redraw

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

As you can see in the test when the view redraw the "p" content is updated but not the input value that has the same data stream as source. Why?

```js
var root = document.body

let v = m.stream({
 field: m.stream()
})

var Hello = {
    view: function() {
        return m("main", [
            m("input", {
                value: v().field(),
                oninput: m.withAttr('value', v().field)
            }),
            m(
                'p', [
                    v().field()
                ]
            ),
            m(
                "button", {
                    "type": "button",
                    onclick: function() {
                        v({
                            field: m.stream()
                        })
                    }
                }, [
                    'save'
                ]
            ),
            m('div', ['Write on input then click save. After click save the P content disappear but input value still. why?'])
        ])
    }
}

m.mount(root, Hello)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mithril/mithril.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mithril-stream"></script>
```

Comment: I think you got a problem because you redefine the stream v's value. You input a new one manually when you click the button. The new value requests itself, from what I can see. I think you shouldn't put the Model object within a stream, but that's just your decision. I can't find a specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bug](https://github.com/MithrilJS/mithril.js/pull/2088). Fixed with the help of very kind mithril staff